# Filter Excel table in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table linked to a data validation list. I have the table filtered to remove blanks. If I select a different item from the data validation list it refreshes the data but cuts out most of it until I refresh the filter. I'm trying to come up with a macro that I can add to my current code to refresh the filter. the filters are years, so 2013,2014,2015,2016 and (blanks). Here's what I've got so far but it just filters out everything

```
Sub sbFilterTable()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter field:=1, _
Criteria1:="*013", Criteria2:="*014", Criteria3:="*015", Criteria4:="*016"

End Sub
```

**Note:** The dates in the first column are in DD/MM/YYYY format so I used a wildcard incase it picked up the full format, even though in the filter options it just says the year. any guidance or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=1/1/2014", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=12/31/2016"
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! I have an updating data source so have just changed the date range to something really wide and it is perfect, thank you so much! :)